# twitter bootstrap 3 button 1px too small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I use the twitter bootstrap 3. I have added a navbar form with an input group into my navigation bar.

The problem is that my button is 1px smaller then the search field. With my compilled version of twitter bootstrap the button is smaller. But If I use the original twitter bootstrap 3.1.1 pre-compiled css, the button is 34px high.

Here is my navigation bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a problem I also had some time ago. Your HTML code is not the problem, but you have to set the sass number precision to 10.

If you are compiling the sass version of the twitter bootstrap yourself, you need to ensure that the number precision is set to 10, by default it often is 5, if you compile sass using grunt-contrib-sass like me, its 3 by default.

Here is the link to the twitter bootstrap documentation where they mention to ensure the precision is 10: [[https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#number-precision]](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#number-precision%5d)

I don't know if you use the grunt plugin grunt-contrib-sass, but if you do, a configuration in your gruntfile like this one, will do the trick:

```
sass: {
    options: {
        unixNewlines: true,
        precision: 10
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.desktop.development.stylesheets.path %>',
            src: ['main.scss'],
            dest: '<%= config.desktop.build.stylesheets.path %>',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
},
```

Here I have the options "precision" that is set to 10 which should solve your size problems.

Comment: Your right the precision was the problem, thank you this fixed my problem